# How to open specific part of the page use jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the link that should open specific part of the another page use jquery.

Simplified view of the index.php file:

```
<?php
if (!isset($a)) $a = '';
switch($a)
{
case 1:
default:
print('<div class"left">the left menu that contains links to specific parts of the     page</div><div class="main">content of the page</div>');
break;
case 2:
echo "second part";
break;
case 3:
echo "third part";
break;
}
?>
```

On this page I'm using jquery to open up certain parts of this file in the "main" DIV.
When I click on the link at the left meny, using jquery, I can open content of the "third part" in "main" DIV;
This page looks like:

```
 --------------------   ----------------------------------
|                    | |                                  |
| the left menu that | |                                  |
| contains links to  | |         third part               |
| specific parts of  | |                                  |
| the     page       | |                                  |
 --------------------   ----------------------------------
```

What I need is jquery code that would allow click on the link located at some other page that will open the index.php file with part of the content as shown in the example above.

Right now, all I can do is open the part of the index.php where the "trird part" is

```
 ----------------------------------
|                                  |
|                                  |
|         third part               |
|                                  |
|                                  |
 ----------------------------------
```

but  I can't open the left meny and the main div at same page using link from another page. How can I do that?

Jquery code that I'm using on that second page is:

```
$('.prt').click(function () {
var adr=$(this).attr('rel');
window.open(adr);
})
```

HTML for link:

```
<div class="prt" rel="index.php?a=3">link</div>
```

Thanks for all the advice & pointers

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the menu always, then remove it from the switch-case statement and put in at the top.

I think you don't want to use `window.open` and open you target page in a cotainer on the right side of your website.

I'd suggest doing this dynamically:

```
$('#main').load('content_3.html'); // Sample!
```